# Calculate total time with out overlapping

Tags: sql, sql-server

Standard work time is Start at 08:00 and End at 16:00, so I declared 2 parameters for this :

```
DECLARE @StartTime TIME = '08:00',
        @EndTime TIME = '16:00'
```

All calculations of time must between the start and end time.

Table1 working hours

```
Id      Date        WorkStartTime     WorkEndTime
-------------------------------------------------------
 1   2019/04/20     08:30            14:20
 2   2019/04/21     09:05            15:15
 3   2019/04/22     08:37            14:22
 4   2019/04/23     08:05            15:00
```

Table2 Leaves

```
Id      Date       LeaveStartTime   LeaveEndTime    
--------------------------------------------------------
 1   2019/04/20     08:00            09:00      
 2   2019/04/21     08:30            16:00
 3   2019/04/22     07:00            08:45
 4   2019/04/22     14:20            17:00
```

and find total leave time for each day without overlap by table 1 (Working hours) (I mean calculate leavetime (from table2) - worktime (table1))

This is the result I need:

```
2019/04/20  30 min 
2019/04/21  80 min -- (35' at first and 45' at end)
2019/04/22  98 min -- (calculate 14:22(workendtime bigger than lavestarttime)   to 16:00 (for @EndTime))
```

I'm hoping to do this in a SQL query. I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: please elaborate how to determine the figure `2019/04/21  80 min`

Comment: why are you considering `2019/04/22` work time for `2019/04/21 80 min` ?

Comment: 80 min is not work time it is leave time (all leave time - work time)=80 min

Comment: i am confused. For the 2nd line in your result `2019/04/21 80 min` it is for `2019/04/21` but why you are using `2019/04/22` working hours in the calculation ? What is the logic here ?

Comment: I don’t understand how work hours and leave hours can overlap, is this some summation for several people?

Comment: it work in 2019/04/21 from 08:37 to 14:22 but it take leave from 08:30 to 16:00 if we decrease work time from leavetime will remain 35' at first and 45' at last of day 35+45=80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation is unclear.  For the third row, you specify 98 minutes, but that is leaving out the 37 minutes at the beginning of the day.

You can do this calculation in SQL Server.  Overlapping time periods are a little messy but definitely possible in SQL.

The following is the logic that I think you want:

```
select l.date,
       sum(datediff(minute, l.LeaveStartTime,
                    (case when l.LeaveStartTime < w.workStartTime then w.workStartTime else l.LeaveStartTime end)
                   ) +
           datediff(minute,
                    (case when l.LeaveEndTime > w.workEndTime then w.workEndTime else l.LeaveEndTime end),
                    l.LeaveEndTime
                   )
          ) as overlaps
from (select l.d, l.date,
             (case when LeaveStartTime < '08:00' then '08:00' else LeaveStartTime end) as LeaveStartTime,
             (case when LeaveEndTime > '16:00' then '16:00' else LeaveEndTime end) as LeaveEndTime
      from leaves l
      where LeaveEndTime > '08:00' and LeaveStartTime < '16:00'
     ) l join
     works w
     on w.date = l.date and
        (l.LeaveStartTime < w.WorkStartTime or
         l.leaveEndTime > w.workEndTime
        )
group by l.date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b0f5c3c0c32a89a54cae53fe46e833e) is a db<>fiddle.

This is trickier than most such problems, because you don't want the overlap -- you want the pieces left over.  This requires considering the "before" and "after" cases for the work times.